# How to call and utilize the generic type of interface implementation

Tags: c#, .net, generics, types, interface

I have a generic type interface that looks somewhat similar-

```
public interface IValidator<T>
{
    ValidationResults Validate(T instance);
}
```

I have a model called Person where

```
public class Person
{
        public BasicDetails BasicDetails { get; set; }
        public AddressDetails AddressDetails { get; set; }
        public ContactDetails ContactDetails { get; set; }
        public Fee Fee { get; set; }
}
```

I have validation classes that looks something like-

```
public class BasicDetailsValidationService : IValidator<BasicDetails>
{
  public ValidationResults Validate(T)
  {
  }
}

public class AddressDetailsValidationService : IValidator<BasicDetails>
{
  public ValidationResults Validate(T)
  {
  }
}
```

Now, I am creating a class where I would like to call the validate method of each validation service.

```
public class MyService : IMyService
{
  readonly IValidator<AddressDetails> addressValidation;
  .
  .
  .
  public MyService(
  IValidator<AddressDetails> addressValidation,
  IValidator<BasicDetails> basicValidation
  .
  .
  .
  ){}

  public async ValidateAsync(Person pe)
  {
    addressValidation.Validate(pe.AddressDetails);
    .
    .
    .
   }
}
```

I would like to know if there is a better way to achieve this. I know usage of IEnumerable. But I cannot use IEnumerable here because interface has generic type.

Comment: Nothing wrong with the implementation as is, but if you need to validate the entire person object, then you can compose validators.

PersonValidator : IValidator<Person>, gets a IValidator<AddressDetails> and IValidator<BasicDetails> in the constructor.

If you don't want lots of different fields, you could create a dictionary<Type, IValidator<T>> and call it as such: validators[pe.AddressDetails.GetType()].Validate(pe.AddressDetails);

Comment: @StanJanssen Dictionary<Type, IValidator<T>> is incorrect since T is not a class